# Borderlands 3 Achievements on Steam stopped rewarding after level 1

Tags: steam, pc, achievements, borderlands-3

I'm currently at level 22 on Borderlands 3 on Steam and just realized that I hadn't seen any achievements pop up like normal. One of the first achievements in the list is You Got Skills which you get after reaching level 2. It looks like it applied the first level but stopped after that.

[image: Steam Achievments Image]

Any idea what happened to stop Steam PC achievements from working for Borderlands 3?

In response to a comment, I always play online and am using Steam Cloud for saves:
[image: Steam Cloud settings image]

Comment: You aren't playing offline, right? ... Also, are you cloud saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems to be a bug**.

Other players are noting the same thing ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/fr9w66/lots_of_achievements_not_unlocking_steam/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/gtc6kn/borderlands_3_steam_achievements_not_working/), [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/397540/discussions/0/4224884861034515432/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/gwb3cc/steam_achievements_not_working/), &c.).

The majority of the cases seem to have started halfway May.
[Gearbox is working on an update](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/borderlands-3-hotfix-05-28-2020/4536732), which was planned for June 4th, and seems to have been postponed due to recent events:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://twitter.com/Borderlands)</sup>

Comment: About 20 achievements popped up as awarded on Friday, June 26, 2020.